# Neo4j graph showing multiple relationship between same nodes on top of each other

Tags: cypher, neo4j

- I am creating multiple relationships between same nodes using the **create unique** cypher query.
- Although The relationship gets created.The graph on localhost:7474 shows the relationships on top of each other.
- When I click on the relationship  to see its properties ,I am able to see the property of only the last created relationship.

Is there any way how I can solve this ?

I am using Neo4j 2.0 community version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visualizing multiple relationships like this is not yet supported by the visualization. It will be added eventually, but there is currently no-one working on it.

For now, I'd suggest using cypher in the browser to find the specific relationship or relationship types you are interested in.